# Give back more than one mysql result in an php class

Tags: php, mysql, class, collections

I'm trying to build my own CMS in classes.
Now I have got a problem when I try to get data from my MySQL database
Instead of one item i'd like to get an collection of all my items

At the end I'd like to get an Object so I can read it out like : $item->id

Here's my code :

```
static function getContentItems($id, $active, $sort_by, $sort_type, $limit) {
    if (isset($id) && !empty($id)) {
        $where .= "WHERE id = ".$id;
    }
    if (isset($active) && !empty($active)) {
        $where .= " AND active = ".$active;
    }
    if (isset($sort_by) && !empty($sort_by)) {
        $where .= " ORDER BY ".$sort_by;

        if (isset($sort_type) && !empty($sort_type)) {
            $where .= " ".$sort_type;
        }
    }
    if (isset($limit) && !empty($limit)) {
        $where .= " LIMIT 0,".$limit;
    }

    if (isset($where) && !empty($where)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM content ".$where;   
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM content";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

    $item = new ContentItem();
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $item->id = $data['id'];
    }   
    return $item;
}
```

}

Comment: no need to write `isset($where)`

Comment: better to use `mysql_fetch_object` if u want to add it on `$item`

Answer (score 1):

dont start your $where string with `.`

```
if (isset($id) && !empty($id)) {
        $where = "WHERE id = ".$id;
    }
```

and alwez print your `$query`

**Better Solution**

```
if (!empty($id) {
        $where = " WHERE id = ".$id;
   if (!empty($active)) {
          $where .= " AND active = ".$active;
     if (!empty($sort_by)) {
          $where .= " ORDER BY ".$sort_by;
        if (!empty($sort_type)) {
            $where .= " ".$sort_type;
        }
    }
  }
}
if (empty($limit)) {
        $where .= " LIMIT 0,".$limit;
}
```

and later

```
$item = new ContentItem();       
$data = array(); $i=0;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {                
         $search_result[$i] = $data;
         $i++;
    }   
 return $search_result;
```

and any id can be retrieve by `$search_result[$i]->id`

Comment: Oke thank you that works, but I rather like to get an Object back instead of an array so I can read it out like $item->id instead of $item['id']

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Arrays?

Like this:

```
$collection = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $item = new ContentItem();
    $item->id = $data['id'];
    $collection[] = $item;     //Appends the item to the array
}
return $collection;
```

You can access your array in this way:

```
$collection = YourClassName::getContentItems(...);
foreach($collection as $item) {
    // do something with each $item
    print_r($item);
}
```

Comment: if we declare array `$item` inside  `while` then each time a new array will b created

Comment: @diEcho You mean if `$collection` is declared inside `while` it causes multiple creations of the array. But here inside the `while` the `$item` is only inserted into the array.

Comment: @diEcho I think it is a custom class that @RR_1990 has created. It should represent a data row from the database.

Comment: @gtatweb that is function name not class name

Comment: @diEcho No, it's the creation of an instance (keyword `new`). Refer here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

Comment: @gtatweb, i understand what u say, but i m saying that `getContentItems` is static function of some class, where u seen the class name in question???

Comment: @gtatweb `$collection[] = $item;`  will give fatal error, u must use `array_push`

Comment: @diEcho ok, i mean that `$item = new ContentItem();` is the creation of an instance (that was your question in the third comment). I should correct the call to `getContentItems` because of the fact of the static function.

Comment: @diEcho `$collection[] = $item;` works, look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 0):

Look into using mysql_fetch_object http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php instead of mysql_fetch_array.. it returns rows the db as an object already